# A separable metric space is second countable

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

A space $X$ is second countable iff $X$ has a countable base. $X$ is separable iff a countable subset $D$ of $X$ with $Cl_{X}(D)=X$ (Such a set $D$ is said to be dense in $X$).

$Cl_{X}(D)=\bigcap\{K\subseteq X:K$ is closed and $D\subseteq K\}$

Comments: I tried using the theorems and definitions from the book, "General Topology" by Stephen Willard. I'm still new to Topology, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Proof: Suppose $X$ is a separable metric space, this implies that $X$ has a countable subset $D$ of $X$ with $Cl_{X}(D)=X$

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the collection of balls of rational radius such that
$\mathcal{H}=\{B(d,\delta):d\in D$ and $\delta\in \mathbb{Q}\}$

Theorem: $\mathcal{H}$ is a base for a topology on $X$ iff
a) $\bigcup_{H\in \mathcal{H}}H=X$

Let $H \in \mathcal{H} \rightarrow \bigcup_{H\in \mathcal{H}}H=X$, since $Cl_{X}(D)=X$

b) whenever $H_{1}, H_{2}\in \mathcal{H}$ with $d\in H_1\cap H_2$, there is some $H_3\in \mathcal{H}$ with $d\in H_3\subset H_1\cap H_2$

Let $H_{1}, H_{2}\in \mathcal{H}$ with $d\in H_{1}\cap H_{2}$. So, there exists $B(d,\delta)\subset H_{1}\cap H_{2}\rightarrow \exists  B(d,\frac{\delta}{2})\subset B(d,\delta)$. Let $H_{3}=B(d,\frac{\delta}{2})$

So, $d\in H_{3}\subset H_{1}\cap H_{2}$

Since $D$ is countable, $\mathcal{H}$ must be countable. So $X$ has a countable base. Therefore $X$ is second countable.

Comment: In (b), that should be $H_1 \cap H_2$ in both places.

Comment: That is what I meant originally. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: It seems pretty good. If I were you I would explain "$\bigcup_{H\in{\cal H}} H = X$ since $Cl_X(D) = X$" with more details.